# tensorflow w/ python 3.9 (in Fedora 33)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, fedora

I installed Fedora 33 and it uses Python 3.9

I don't see any builds of Tensorflow w/ Python 3.9 in pypi or [google](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location).

Is this because TF needs to be ported to Python 3.9 ... or because no one bothered to build it ?

IE, should I try to build TF w/ Python 3.9 ... or should I make a python 3.8 venv and install from pypi ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue on my system. The latest Python currently supported by Tensorflow is 3.8. You can get your tensorflow code working again by running:

> dnf install python3.8

Once you have that installed, you can get pip working again by running:

> python3.8 -m ensurepip --user

Also, the packages you previously installed through pip should be available at:

> ~/.local/lib/python3.x/site-packages/

The following release notes were helpful for me:
[Fedora 33 Release Notes on Python](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f33/release-notes/developers/Development_Python/#_updated_python_package_to_latest_version)

Comment: Nice.  This is simplier than "python3.8 -m venv mumble" (which calls ensurepip)

Comment: I've used conda to manage my environment  `dnf install conda`. Then its simple as `pip install tensorflow` that manages the latest python version needed